# Can a Spring JpaTransactionManager be assigned in Java code?

Tags: xml, spring, jpa

Summary: In my Spring `XML` I am passing a Properties object to a factory class that creates a wrapper class around a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. If I use a property value, say `isTransactional==true`, to create a `JpaTransactionManager` in the wrapper class, will it work correctly with `@Transactional` classes? Or does the `JpaTransactionManager` have to be declared in the Spring `XML`?

`JpaConfigFactory` creates a `JpaConfig` instance which wraps a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`.
`jpaProperties` is a `Properties` object used to set properties such as the JPA provider (e.g., Hibernate), `DataSource`, `PersistenceUnit` name, etc.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean"
    p:staticMethod=sample.JpaConfigFactory.newJpaConfig">
    <property>
        <list>
            <ref bean="jpaProperties"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The usual way to set up a `JpaTransactionManager` would be to retrieve the `EntityManagerFactory` from the `JpaConfig` instance and set it as a property:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

My question is whether this could be done in the `JpaConfig` constructor:

```
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
private JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager;
public JpaConfig( Properties props )
{
    ...
    if ( Boolean.parseBoolean( props.getProperty( "isTransactional" ) )
    {
        jpaTransactionManager = 
            new JpaTransactionManager( entityManagerFactory );
    }
}
```

Can this be made to work?

Comment: could you please post your sample code?

Comment: Why? When doing database work you need transactions... Not sure why you want to switch those of. Instead of hacking around with properties use profiles instead. But I would advice against turning of transactions as that will eventually lead to nice to debug issues.

Comment: Some applications don't need transactions. I don't see the point in not being able to exclude them. In any case I am still looking for an answer to the question.